# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean but expression returns void

Tags: java

In `userInput.equals("0") ?` part both resulting expressions return void type. Why then it tells me that the expression returns String?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseConverter {

    private static final int SENTINEL = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        askInput();
    }

    private static void askInput() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        System.out.println("This is converter");
        System.out.println("0 to stop");
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter hex: ");
            userInput = reader.nextLine();

            userInput.equals("0")  ? break : System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Since when can you use ternary operators like that?

Comment: use  `T a = x ? y : z` you must be `return` not void value...

Comment: You must use ternary operator to calculate a value  like `int max = a > b ? a : b;` not other things.

Answer (score 2):

You must switch from *ternary* operator to *if/else* statement

```
if(userInput.equals("0")) {
  break;
} else {
  System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
}
```

This code can be reduced to:

```
if(userInput.equals("0")) {
  break;
}
System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
```

Comment: Does ternary operator always have to be assigned to something?

Comment: Yes, and No.... I mean, ternary must produce a result, in both cases the same data type, the result can be assigned to a variable or used on a test condition... but ternary is not a flow control statment like if/else/else if

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the ternary operator like that, instead do this:

```
if(userInput.equals("0")) break;
System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's better to use use `do{} while()` loop like this :

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter hex: ");
    userInput = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
} while (!userInput.equals("0"));
```

---

Which mean, repeat until `userInput` should equal to `0`, you don't need to use `break` in this case.

---

For a better solution, you still need to use `try` and `catch` to avoid `NumberFormatException` :

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter hex: ");
    userInput = reader.nextLine();
    try {
        System.out.println(userInput + "hex = " + Integer.valueOf(userInput, 10) + " decimal");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Number");
    }

} while (!userInput.equals("0"));
```